Cannot find resize completion event when creating trigger for cloud function to handle Firebase image resize completion from extension
I have configured the image resize extension on a Firebase storage bucket and that is working fine. I am trying to create a Firebase/Cloud function to receive the resize completion event and do something.
To do that I need to setup a trigger but I can't find the event "firebase.extensions.storage-resize-images.v1.onSuccess" in the eventType drop down. For the Trigger Type on main screen I select "Other trigger" then on the side panel Trigger Type I have "Google Sources", for Event Provider I choose Eventarc then in the Even Type drop down that comes up I don't see the option for "firebase.extensions.storage-resize-images.v1.onSuccess" or any other resize-images event. There are only two main Event Type buckets in the drop down - "Direct" and "via Cloud Audit Logs".
I am missing some configuration here. How do I setup the function to trigger on firebase.extensions.storage-resize-images.v1.onSuccess event from the image-resize extension on firebase?
Thanks,
Sanjay.

To close this out, I was able to address it through the following firebase function declaration
export const imgResizeCustomEvthandler = onCustomEventPublished("firebase.extensions.storage-resize-images.v1.onSuccess", async (evt: any) => {
// Do you want to here
}

